# A fleshed-out version of the Noncommutative Geometry proof of the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem?

Tags: reference-request, noncommutative-geometry

In Connes's book on noncommutative geometry, he outlines a rather short "algebraic" proof of the Gauss-Bonnet theorem that uses multilinear forms. (Start reading on page 19 of the [book](http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/book94bigpdf.pdf)) This is given as motivation for cyclic cohomology.

Where can I find a fleshed-out version of this proof?

Comment: Where exactly in the book is this outline?

Comment: @Jonas: I've added the location to the question.

Answer (score 5):

After many days of consistent effort, finally I could find a complete article that speaks about proving the various corollaries and theorems of  Gauss-Bonnet , even though the article starts with a preliminary version of the proof ( considering Riemann metrics and the Euler forms, it does have a different versions of the proof, and the whole article is related to that ).

It does have a usage of Multi-linear forms ( in the chapter 'curvature' ) , but I think this is an elegant article that completely speaks about the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem in various view points. The article which I am talking about is [Lectures on geometry of manifolds by Liviu I. Nicolaescu](http://www.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf) .

Thank you. I think it will surely serve your purpose. I will edit and add some more articles, once I verify that they contain something related to this stuff.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Iyengar!

Comment: Thanks a lot sir @JonBannon

Comment: @JonBannon : But, can I ask you one thing sir ? . In the article you have provided, I can't find any proof of Gauss-Bonnet Theorem, but it simply uses some remarkable stability which is a consequence of that theorem and by combining with the theory of multi-linear forms , one can show as an analogue that some trilinear map should be some constant as predicted by the Gauss-Bonnet theorem. But Am I right ? .